# Can't find proper class for webscraping on Etsy

Tags: python, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape product information from Etsy, and am following a relatively simple tutorial to do so.

This is my current code:

```
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'}

#opening up connection, grabbing url 
url = "https://www.etsy.com/sg-en/search/bath-and-beauty/soaps?q=green+beauty&explicit=1&ref=pagination&page=1"
uclient = ureq(url)
page_html = uclient.read()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'lxml')
print(page_soup.p)

#grabs each product 
listings = page_soup.findAll("li", {"class":"wt-list-unstyled wt-grid__item-xs-6 wt-grid__item-md-4 wt-grid__item-lg-3 wt-order-xs-0 wt-order-sm-0 wt-order-md-0 wt-order-lg-0 wt-order-xl-0 wt-order-tv-0 grid__item-xl-fifth tab-reorder"})
len(listings)
```

The last step repeatedly outputs 0, specifically for this class, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Based on the inspect code, this is the appropriate class name & css class type to be using.
[Etsy Inspect Code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X45Jj.jpg)

Would really appreciate any help! Thanks (-:

Comment: first check if page doesn't use `javascript` to add item. Turn off JavScript in browser and load paga to see what it show. Next check what you get in `page_soup` - maybe server send HTML with different classes - or send Captcha to block bots/scripts. Finally use simpled classes - ie. `find_all("li", {"class": "tab-reorder"})` - you don't have to use all classes which you see in browser. You may even start with only `"li"` to see if it can find them.

Comment: @firas, checked the javascript and it's fine! used your class & it worked! how did you figure out the class?

Comment: first I checked only `li` and I get ~150 items. Next I check code in Inspect Code and I keep only `tab-reorder` which means something. Classes like `grid_item` can be used in many other elements and server may uses different values/classes for different devices - notebook, tablet, phone. Later I saw that all `li` are in `dev` with similar class `tab-reorder-container` and this reduced items to 65 - like items on page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can get 65 items like on page using simpler

```
soup.find("div", {"class": "tab-reorder-container"}).find_all("li", {"class":"tab-reorder"})
```

First I use `find()` to get region with all items and later I use `find_all()` to find only `li` in this region.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/601.3.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0.2 Safari/601.3.9'}

#opening up connection, grabbing url 
url = "https://www.etsy.com/sg-en/search/bath-and-beauty/soaps?q=green+beauty&explicit=1&ref=pagination&page=1"

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BS(r.text, 'lxml')
print(soup.p)

#grabs each product 
listings = soup.find('div', {'class': 'tab-reorder-container'}).find_all("li", {"class":"tab-reorder"})
print(len(listings))

for item in listings:
    item = item.find('h3')
    if item:
        print(item.get_text(strip=True))
```

But problem is this page uses `JavaScript` to add items to page and it finds 65 items but most of them are empty because `BS` can't run `JavaScript` to add all values to HTML.

It may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`. Or it may need to check if other data are somewhere in `JavaScript` on page or if `JavaScript` doesn't read data from other url - and then you can use this url with `requests`

---

**EDIT:**

Version which use Selenium to load page in Chrome/Firefox, close popup window, scroll it to the end of page, and get elements with `BeautifulSoup` and without `BeautifulSoup`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import selenium.webdriver
import time

#opening up connection, grabbing url 
url = "https://www.etsy.com/sg-en/search/bath-and-beauty/soaps?q=green+beauty&explicit=1&ref=pagination&page=1"

driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@data-gdpr-single-choice-accept]').click()

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(1.5)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

print('--- version 1 - BeautifulSoup ---')

html = driver.page_source

soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.p)

#grabs each product 
listings = soup.find('div', {'class': 'tab-reorder-container'}).find_all("li", {"class":"tab-reorder"})
print(len(listings))

for item in listings:
    item = item.find('h3')
    if item:
        print(item.get_text(strip=True))

print('--- version 2 - Selenium ---')

#grabs each product 
listings = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.tab-reorder-container li.tab-reorder')
print(len(listings))

for item in listings:
    item = item.find_element_by_css_selector('h3')
    if item:
        print(item.text.strip())
```

Comment: hmm i tried this code but it keeps telling me that str doesn't have a find_all attribute

Comment: @firas also when i tried looping through using listings = page_soup.findAll("li", {'class' = 'tab-reorder'}) i got a result of 130; but a bunch of these results are

 [<li class="wt-list-unstyled wt-grid__item-xs-6 wt-grid__item-md-4 wt-grid__item-lg-3 wt-order-xs-17 wt-order-sm-17 wt-order-md-11 wt-order-lg-9 wt-order-xl-7 wt-order-tv-7 grid__item-xl-fifth tab-reorder">
<div>
<p class="screen-reader-only">Loading...</p>
<div class="wt-display-block">
<div class="wt-skeleton-ui wt-skeleton-ui--image-landscape"></div>
<div class="wt-skeleton-ui wt-skeleton-ui--body-01 wt-mt-xs-1">...

Comment: it's basically just a bunch of these & i don't know what to do with this information -- really appreciate your help!

Comment: and this is what I said before - it uses `JavaScript` to add information to `HTML` in place of `Loading...` but `BS` can't run `JavaScript` and you may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript` and it can gives you `HTML` with all information. But it may need also to scroll page to force `JavaScript` to add information - because many pages add items only wnen user scroll page.

Comment: I added code which uses [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to get all elements. It needed to open browser, close popup window, scroll page - so it works longer.

Comment: thank you so much this was so helpful!! really appreciate you taking the time to help a complete stranger (-":

Answer (score 0):

An idiosyncrasy of bs4 (or maybe I don't fully understand it...), try this instead:

```py
listings = page_soup.find_all("li", class_="wt-list-unstyled wt-grid__item-xs-6 wt-grid__item-md-4 wt-grid__item-lg-3 wt-order-xs-0 wt-order-sm-0 wt-order-md-0 wt-order-lg-0 wt-order-xl-0 wt-order-tv-0 grid__item-xl-fifth tab-reorder")
```